Laravel DigitalOcean Spaces Upload Issue
I'm currently working on a Laravel application where I need to upload files to DigitalOcean Spaces. I've set up my spaces disk in config/filesystems.php as follows:
'spaces' => [

    'driver' => 's3',

    'key' => env('DO_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),

    'secret' => env('DO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),

    'endpoint' => env('DO_ENDPOINT'),

    'region' => env('DO_DEFAULT_REGION'),

    'bucket' => env('DO_BUCKET'),

    'visibility' => 'public',

],


Here's the controller method I'm using for the upload:
public function upload(Request $request)

{

    $request->validate([

        'file' => 'required|file|max:2048',

        'directory' => 'nullable|string',

    ]);

    try {

        $file = $request->file('file');

        $directory = $request->input('directory', 'uploads');

        $directory = trim($directory) !== '' ? $directory : 'uploads';

        $filePath = $file->store($directory, ['disk' => 'spaces', 'visibility' => 'public']);

        if (!$filePath) {

            throw new \Exception('The store method did not return a valid path.');

        }

        $fileUrl = Storage::disk('spaces')->url($filePath);

        Log::info('File uploaded successfully', [

            'file_path' => $filePath,

            'file_url' => $fileUrl,

        ]);

        return response()->json(['url' => $fileUrl, 'path' => $filePath], 201);

    } catch (\Throwable $e) {

        Log::error('File upload failed with error', [

            'exception_message' => $e->getMessage(),

            'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),

            'disk_config' => config('filesystems.disks.spaces'),

        ]);

        return response()->json([

            'error' => 'File upload failed',

            'message' => $e->getMessage(),

        ], 500);

    }

}

The problem is that:

No file is uploaded.

No folder is created in the specified Space.

I don't see any errors logged, even in storage/logs/laravel.log.


I've tested the configuration, and it seems correct. The store method returns null, but I can't figure out why. I've double-checked the following:

My access key and secret key are correct.

The Space has write permissions.



Questions:

Has anyone faced a similar issue where no file or folder is created, and no error is shown?

Could this be related to a misconfiguration in the spaces disk?

Is there a way to debug this further or force Laravel to give more detailed error messages?



Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
